# Lose dynamic content after page refresh in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic-content

Here is my problem: I'm developing a mobile web app with jQuery Mobile and I have to create dynamic content.

In the first page I have a listview with some `<li>`elements. When I click in one of these `<li>` I go to another page and create the content dynamically. So the content of the second page is different for every `<li>` of the first page.

My problem is when I refresh the second page all dynamic content disappears because it has lost the parameters. To solve this I tried to use the querystring, for example `<a href="secondPage?=id=2">` but this did not work.

What I ask you is if there is another way to pass the parameters through pages with jQuery Mobile so that when I refresh the page I don't lose the content.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash` so save/load your data. Just save the data there in a string format on data change an on page load check if anything is there.

The data in there will be appended to your URL as a hash: `example.com/url#yourdata`

Comment: Thank you for your answer..It works using the href attribute in each <li> using the id on "pagebeforeshow"..Is there anyway to pass the parameters through pages without using the href attribute?I mean I have an object with 40 parameters and I don't want to show in the url all them..I find it a bit unconfortable and not very good..thank you!

Comment: Oh thank you for your response..I also thought about using cookies but can't use cookies since my professor doesn't like it..any other suggestion?! thank you in any case

Comment: You could get really fancy and use an HTML5 `sessionStorage` object :)

Comment: Session Storage?!I really didn't knew about that..I'll try it :) thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's a nice technique but be careful, it's not widely supported amongst browsers. Especially older browsers tend to not support it.

Comment: See here for a nice demo of `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`: http://html5demos.com/storage :)

Answer (score 0):

Use http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

just save the parameters u need in the local db and then get it on the second page to use.